# passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast in C

Tags: c

Im trying to put this numbers from txt file:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1
```

In one integer array with this code:

```
    char texto[Max_Linhas][Tamanho_Linha];
//int tamanhodagrelha
int i=0,tamanhodagrelha, cont, tam, NumLinhas, l, c;
int grelha[Max_Linhas][Max_Linhas];

fch = fopen("ficheiro.txt", "r");      

if (fch == NULL)
{
    printf("O arquivo não foi aberto.\n");
}

    //Lê conjunto de caracteres ate \n ou \t
    fscanf(fch, "%d", &tamanhodagrelha);

    NumLinhas = (tamanhodagrelha+2);        

    while( i<NumLinhas && fgets(texto[i],Tamanho_Linha,fch))
    {
        i++;
    }

    for (cont=1; cont<= tamanhodagrelha; cont++)
    {
        tam=0;
        l=0;
        while( texto[cont][tam] != '\n')
        {
            if(texto[cont][tam] != ' ')
            {
                for(c=0; c< tamanhodagrelha; c++)
                {
                    grelha[l][c] = atoi(texto[cont][tam]);
                }
            }
            tam++;
        }
            l++;
            printf("\n");
    }
```

But i have this erro (passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast) in the line "grelha[l][c] = atoi(texto[cont][tam]);" and i dont know what to do.

Comment: Note: never use `atoi` in production code -- it provides *zero* error reporting. It will happily return `0` for `atoi("dogs");` and you will never discover the error. At minimum, use `sscanf` or preferably `strtol` (which provides full error handling capabilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to parse single-digit integers from `char` to `int`. However, `atoi` expects a C string (a `const char*`), and therefore you cannot pass it a plain char.

Instead of `atoi`, this could be sufficient (**for single digit integer**):

```
grelha[l][c] = texto[cont][tam] - '0';
```

If you are thinking of parsing multiple-digit integers, then you shouldn't use char[][], since they can only contain one character (and thus a single digit number) per entry as per your usage.

Comment: So, what is the best way to put this numbers from txt file in one int array[][]?

Comment: If you are just handling single digit integers, you can just follow my answer.
If not, you will have to declare your `textto` to char[][][max_length_of_integer], or char* [][] If you are going to use dynamic allocation for each integer. Then you can use `fgets` to read from file, and `atoi` to convert to integer.

Comment: Or simply read each line into a buffer with `fgets` and then use `sscanf` with an offset from the beginning incorporating the `"%n"` specifier to report the number of characters consumed with each conversion to be added to your offset from the beginning. Or, instead of `sscanf`, you can use `strtol` with the `endptr` parameter to work though the buffer converting each number contained within.